# What's a Non-Delivery Custom Renderer?

Tags: tridion

[SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_B8ABDA514B24443EBCDB4AE382387553) describes the use case for Renderers as "manipulating the output produced by the rendering process" for Component Presentations.  This falls between Content Manager and Content Delivery, specifically under Content Distribution / Publishing.

Rather than adding a Template Building Block (TBB) to all templates, we can use a custom renderer to "globally" change all CP's output. We can also use a renderer to publish item types not currently rendered. We can add a custom resolver for this item type along with a custom renderer and CD-side code.

We would implement `IRenderer` under `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering` in a .NET project and add the resulting dll to the CMS's GAC.

### Questions

I can see how we would use a renderer to maybe manipulate or even wrap all outputted markup or maybe wrap all CPs.

- Is this for "raw" manipulation of whatever our templates output? In other words, **do we get access to any of the CM or CD APIs?**
- **Does this renderer logic apply to *all* publications and templates in a given CMS instance?**
- The documentation refers to *item types*, **are those *Tridion* item types such as TBBs**?

Bart Koopman also describes how Custom Renderers work in the context of the other extension points in [How To Tackle Integrations article on SDLTridionWorld](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/tackleintegrations.aspx).

I understand  is distinct from [Delivery-Side Renderers described by Jaime Santos Alcón](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2011/02/tridion-2011-ga-content-delivery.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed something that would be executed every time the standard renderer is invoked. While the use case for Custom **Resolvers** is easier to understand, the principles are the same and they're both part of the Publishing Pipeline.

I will always advise that instead of creating a custom renderer that will execute every time you render a template, you should use a Template Building Block that is added to all of your templates with that same functionality. Creating a custom renderer will likely *be forgotten* at some point in time and then you'll wonder why the output is different all of a sudden when *nothing changed*.

Comment: Thanks, Nuno! For every *global*, "every time" requirement I get, there's almost always an exception. I can see where TBBs give us better flexibility.